# Git Repository in Dropbox Folder With Team Members Checking Out Different Branches Simultaneously

Tags: git, dropbox, collaboration

At work we host all of our projects in Dropbox folders.  Inside these Dropbox folders we have Git projects.  If I checkout a branch on Git, that branch is checked out for everyone on our team, because the folders are in Dropbox.

Is there a way that two team members can checkout different branches at the same time while in dropbox?

Comment: The best answer to this is likely going to be "don't put `git` repositories or working directories in Dropbox-synced folders", for a couple reasons 1) `git` isn't designed to work that way, 2) it's going to make a nice network traffic amplifier, and 3) see the above question regarding problems encountered when doing so...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different working dir, outside dropbox folder, using either [git worktree](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows) from a recent git, or [git-new-workdir](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir) script from git contribs. Likely the latter is unix-specific due to usage of symlinks (in NTFS *there is* support of symlinks, but in a slightly different syntax, so one need to hack the script a bit)

Comment: Worktree might do it.  But I get the following error: git: 'worktree' is not a git command.  Must it be installed?

Comment: Do you have a recent (>2.5 git)? If not, you may go with git new-workdir from contrib.